# Google Endpoints on GKE (ESP + gRPC) - how to debug this further?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After following
[Getting started with Cloud Endpoints on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine) and [deploying the API and backend](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#deploy_backend) everything *looks like* it's working (spoiler alert, it's not);

- My application's deployed on a cluster.
- A single pod is deployed in Kubernetes.
- The pod is running two containers ([ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/glossary#extensible_service_proxy) and my GPRC service)

  1. `gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1`
  2. `gcr.io/my-app/server:latest`

...both are running; `kubectl get pods` yields:

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-855d8447f-nnvz8        2/2     Running   0          24m
```

[Need improved/HTTPS-centric GKE Ingress + ESP + gRPC example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-samples/issues/52) was very helpful in getting me this far.

Bad news; HTTP requests from my Angular app (running on `http://localhost:4200`) result in **500 Internal Server Error**.

I ran through [Troubleshooting Cloud Endpoints in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-gke-deployment) and couldn't see anything that applied (there is nothing obviously wrong).

OK. Time to debug.

Looking at the ESP (Docker container) logs with `kubectl logs -f my-app-855d8447f-nnvz8 -c esp`, I can see the preflight request (`OPTIONS`) and subsequent HTTP `POST` request.

```
INFO:Fetching an access token from the metadata service
INFO:Fetching the service config ID from the rollouts service
INFO:Fetching the service configuration from the service management service
INFO:Attribute zone: us-central1-a
INFO:Attribute project_id: my-cloud-project
INFO:Attribute kube_env: KUBE_ENV

nginx: [warn] Using trusted CA certificates file: /etc/nginx/trusted-ca-certificates.crt

143.159.55.199 - - [12/Jan/2020:17:34:11 +0000] "OPTIONS /v1/documents?key=Ei2ZvlV5zASIkuRf4LRl&format=JSON&showDefaults=false HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "http://localhost:4200/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
143.159.55.199 - - [12/Jan/2020:17:34:11 +0000] "POST /v1/documents?key=Ei2ZvlV5zASIkuRf4LRl&format=JSON&showDefaults=false HTTP/1.1" 500 242 "http://localhost:4200/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
```

The CORS (`OPTIONS`) request results in HTTP 204, however the `POST` request is HTTP 500. So there's clearly a problem here.

Despite plenty of logging, there are no logs in my grpc server; `kubectl logs -f my-app-855d8447f-nnvz8 -c server` yields nothing. So

- The Kubernetes pod is healthy and both containers arerunning.
- The ESP is starting and successfully using the metadata service
- CORS is working (it's wide-open while I'm developing)
- The gRPC service is running but not being hit (no logs)

Somewhere between CORS and POST HTTP requests, it's going wrong and the gRPC service never gets called.

I can't find any errors; How can I debug what's going on between ESP/nginx and my gRPC server?

For completeness, here's my deployment yaml (with added comments):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
        # The default value for the backend address is http://127.0.0.1:8080
        args: [
          "--http_port=8081",

          # My gPRC service is running on port 8080 on the same VM.
          "--backend=grpc://127.0.0.1:8080",
          "--service=my-project.endpoints.my-project-dev.cloud.goog",
          "--rollout_strategy=managed",

          # Makes ESP return code 200 for location /healthz,
          # instead of forwarding the request to the backend.
          "--healthz=healthz",

          # Wide-open CORS during development.
          "--cors_preset=basic",
          "--cors_allow_origin=*",
        ]
        # HEALTH CHECK START
        # Used by ingress to perform health check
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8081
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
        # HEALTH CHECK END
      - name: server
        image: gcr.io/my-project-dev/server:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

The CORS response headers from the ESP/nginx container are:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 12 Jan 2020 17:34:11 GMT
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 google
```

I don't expect anyone to magic-up an answer, but right now I'm unsure of how to debug this any further when everthing looks good?

Comment: Are you able to ssh into `esp` constainers and check if you can connect to `server` container by hand? Something like `kubectl exec -it my-app-855d8447f-nnvz8 --container server -- /bin/bash`?

Comment: Yes. I connected with `kubectl exec -it my-app-855d8447f-nnvz -c server -- /bin/bash` And once in the `server` I can see the gRPC Python service running with `ps -ax`

Comment: I also ssh'd into the nginx proxy container (`esp`) too and `cat  /var/log/nginx/error.log` but that only contained `Using trusted CA certificates file: /etc/nginx/trusted-ca-certificates.crt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new day and a solution. I'll briefly explain the solution, but focus more on *how* I discovered it and what I would do differently.

**Problem**

The "Compute Engine default service account" was missing some permissions. [Getting started with Cloud Endpoints on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine) does *not* use Datastore. My app does. Simply going to IAM & admin > IAM, and adding the "Cloud Datastore User" role to the service account fixed my problem.

**Lessons**

**1.** Logging in `__init__` of the Python gPRC server doesn't provide as much cover as it seems. AFAICT, the main gRPC service module was being called/loaded in some way but the insufficient permissions meant `from google.cloud import datastore` prevented my Cloud log statements from being executed:

```py
# This requires "Cloud Datastore User" role.
from google.cloud import datastore

class MyServer(myservice_pb2_grpc.MyServer):
    """Implements the GRPC interface to handle client calls."""

    def __init__(self):
        # Logging using CloudLoggingHandler was never executed.
        logger.info('__init__')

def serve():
    """Runs a gRPC server to handle client calls."""
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    myservice_pb2_grpc.add_MyServiceServicer_to_server(MyServer(), server)

    # The default value for the backend address is http://127.0.0.1:8080
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:8080')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

**2.** While the Container logs did include a very helpful error message, it was hidden by the default Stackdriver filters:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="standard-cluster-2"
resource.labels.namespace_id="default"
resource.labels.project_id="my-project-dev"
resource.labels.zone:"us-central1-a"
resource.labels.container_name=("esp" OR "server")
resource.labels.pod_id="my-app-855d8447f-nnvz8"
```

Seeing my error required a `resource.type` of `api`. Moreover, only the `project_id` of the resource labels was relevant. I strongly recommend viewing **api** logs for your project. Don't just view **container** logs:

```
resource.type="api"
resource.labels.project_id="json-schema-dev"
```

In my case, the exact error could be found with Stackdriver filters set to

```
resource.type="api"
resource.labels.project_id="json-schema-dev"
jsonPayload.log_message:("Exception calling application: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.")
```

**3.** Given that I couldn't find the error in the Stackdriver logs, where did I find it? The browser console. The humble browser console. I was looking only at the network tab of the Developer Console, seeing the HTTP 500 response, and going straight to the Cloud Console.

**4.** View the full error message. The error received by the browser may render as:

```
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url:"http://34.107.225.145/v1/documents:inferkey=123&format=JSON&showDefaults=false"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for http://123.456.789.342 500 Internal Server Error".
error: {code: 2, message:...
```

I didn't expand the `error` property which was truncated with ellipsis. Upon expanding this I got:

```
code: 2
message: "Exception calling application: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions."
```

**Summary**

- Logging in `__init__` may not be enough.

  - Consider logging in `serve()`
- Merely importing a module for which you have insufficient permissions may prevent log statements from being executed.
- Check `api` logs, not just `container` logs.

  - Kubernetes links to Container logs for convenience, but the default filters are decidedly inconvenient.
- Spend more time looking the client error, and don't be so quick to move to the server.

  - Expand the console error message as much as possible (go beyond the response code)